# How to prevent Process builder from triggering multiple times instead of one time

Tags: process-builder, chatter

I have a process builder in opportunity it will post a chatter message to user's record when the opportunity status is changed.

The process builder works,If the Opportunity status is contract accepted, it will send a chatter message to that record .But my process builder get triggered multiple times instead of one time and send the email also.

I don't write any email alerts but i get the emails .Can anyone help me how to prevent process builder triggering from multiple times.

[image: PB Action][image: Chatter messages in opportunity record]

Comment: Can you edit the post and add more details like the criteria for the process builder and also when will this action be performed with exact conditions you mentioned

Comment: agree with the above comment more details are required, the below answer may or may not be correct, it depends on the criteria etc as to how to asnwer this question.
also describe the requirement too, because often the flow written does not match the requirement and the wrong approach has been taken.
this is a called the XY problem. solving for Y when actually X is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Advanced Options section to ensure recursion is not allowed? This will prevent the process from executing multiples times in a single transaction.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.process_advanced_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: This answer may seem correct in some circumstances but actually could be completely wrong in others.
For example the issue could be a poorly written criteria and flow that causes recursion, when actually the requirement could be quite simple.

Of course know way for you to know this unfortunately you will have to build rep (which you are trying to do, so keep it up), but you may have to give time for someone to tell the question writer that their question needs improvement.

i any case even if you were right with your answer, you should provide more detailed reponse so that the OP can follow s